# Passing a struct as an argument

Tags: c, struct

I have been trying to pass a struct as an argument, but I seem to have an issue with the different structs.
My goal is to create a generic function that takes a struct and then overwrites a field in particular struct.

```
struct information{
        int number;
 };
typedef struct information Jack;
typedef struct information Joe;
```

and then a function.

```
foo(struct information Name , int randomNumber) {
     Name.number = randomNumber;
}
```

However, when I print Jack.number and Joe.number, it prints 0.

```
void main() {
    int h =5;
    foo(Joe,h);
    foo(Jack,h);
    printf("%d",Jack.number);
    printf("%d",Joe.number);
  }
```

Is there any way of solving this issue and create such a generic function?

Comment: Where is your print code?

Comment: How are you sure randomNumber was not 0.

Comment: your foo-function must return a information struct or if void use pointers.

Comment: `void main()` should be `int main(void)`. If you're using a textbook that told you to use `void main()`, find one written by someone who knows the language.

Comment: Why do you use `typedef` names as variables?

Comment: That is exactly something that I am not sure of. Should I just create typedef struct information Person; and then Person Jack; Person Joe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the `struct` by value. Whatever changes you make to `Name` in `foo` affects only the copy of the object in `foo`. It does not change the value of the object in the calling function.

If you want the change to take effect in the calling function, you'll need to pass a pointer to it. For that, you'll need to change the interface of `foo`.

```
foo(struct information* Name , int randomNumber) {
     Name->number = randomNumber;
}
```

You'll need to change the call also to match the interface.

```
foo(&Joe,h);
foo(&Jack,h);
```

Comment: what if I would like to access the value inside "foo"? So for instance, inside foo, I would like to do: Joe.name = Joe.name - 2?

Comment: I seem to get an error: expected expression before Joe

Comment: @JohnnyBravo, you can do that but don't. Let the function work only with the arguments passed to it.

Comment: @JohnnyBravo, don't make this a consulting session :) If you have more questions, create another SO post.

Comment: Thanks. And should I also create one typedef Person. And then just do Person Joe, Person Jack?

Comment: @JohnnyBravo, sure. In that case, it will be better to use `typedef struct Person { ... } Person;`.

Comment: Ok, so then should I just stay with:foo(struct information* Name , int randomNumber) or should I change it to something else, because I have a typedef Person and then Person Jack and Person Joe

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should pass a pointer to your struct, like this:

```
foo(struct information *Name , int randomNumber) {
     Name->number = randomNumber;
}
```

You would call your function like this:

```
foo (&Jack, 42);
```

[Edit] Oh, and there's something wrong with your declarations as well. Maybe you could declare your objects like this:

```
typedef struct informationStruct {
        int number;
} Information;

Information Jack;
Information Joe;
```

and your function like this:

```
foo(Information *Name , int randomNumber) {
     Name->number = randomNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C passes structs by value (as every other argument type). If you want to see changes outside of the function, pass it by reference:

```
void foo(struct information *name, int randomNumber) {
    name->number = randomNumber;
}

foo(&joe, 42);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that C passes, values to function and not reference. So as everyone has mentioned,you could pass the address of the structure(which you want to modify) to the function and then the changes made to the structure inside that function would be automatically reflected in main function.